# Is possible in Laravel Nova 4 use a field of nested relation in search fields?

Tags: laravel, search, laravel-nova

I have the following db:

- Showcases (n to 1) Workers (1 to 1) Users

I need in the showcase resource section find showcase by user's name. In the Nova's documentation they explains that is possible search by related field like this:

```
public static $search = [
'id', 'author.name'
];
```

If I try 'worker.user.name' it doesn't works. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to define it on your Laravel Model, otherwise it wont work.

```
use Laravel\Nova\Query\Search\SearchableRelation;

/**
 * Get the searchable columns for the resource.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public static function searchableColumns()
{
    return ['id', new SearchableRelation('author', 'name')];
}
```

Comment: @boh if this is your answer you need mark it as answer. So people can find it back afterwards if they're having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this package [titasgailius/search-relations](https://github.com/TitasGailius/nova-search-relations).

```
<?php

namespace App\Nova\Resources\OrderManagement;

use App\Nova\Resources\Resource;
use Titasgailius\SearchRelations\SearchesRelations;

class Showcase extends Resource
{
    use SearchesRelations;

    /**
     * The relationship columns that should be searched.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    public static $searchRelations = [
        'worker.user' => ['name'],
    ];

    /**
     * Get the fields displayed by the resource.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function fields(Request $request)
    {
        return [];
    }
}
```

*Assuming you have set the `belongsTo` relationships properly in your models.